# PHP parse .csv file into array and add up ONLY certain elements of certain rows

Tags: php, arrays, loops, csv, currency

I've got a **csv file** with column headers. What I'm looking for is, that how can I take out **the number from column no. 9** (currency amount) from only those rows, which contain **"XYZxxxx" code in the 2nd column** and add them up with **only the same kind of currency** specified in **col no. 10**?

My approach until now is:

1. Parse the content of csv into php array.
2. Explode the content into different rows.
3. Check for rows containing "XYZxxxx".

Then I cannot figure out, how to take the amount of currency and the type of currency out from these and sum the up with the same type.

I'm thinking that I can look separately for "EUR", "GBP" & "USD" values and group the rows into different variables based on the results, but is it a correct approach or am I overthinking it?

Comment: Show code please.

Answer (score 1):

Some simple solution:

```
$array = [
    [10, 'DOLLAR'],
    [20, 'DOLLAR'],
    [25, 'EURO'],
    [20, 'DOLLAR'],
    [25, 'EURO'],
];

$sums = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (empty($sums[$item[1]])) {
        $sums[$item[1]] = $item[0];
    } else {
        $sums[$item[1]] += $item[0];
    }
}

echo'<pre>',print_r($sums),'</pre>';
//Array
//(
//    [DOLLAR] => 50
//    [EURO] => 50
//)
```

Extended example:

```
$array = [
    [10, 'DOLLAR', 'XYZ1010'],
    [20, 'DOLLAR', 'ABC'],
    [25, 'EURO', 'XYZ1010'],
    [20, 'DOLLAR', 'XYZ1010'],
    [25, 'EURO', 'ABC'],
];

$sums = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (strpos($item[2], 'XYZ') !== false) {
        if (empty($sums[$item[1]])) {
            $sums[$item[1]] = $item[0];
        } else {
            $sums[$item[1]] += $item[0];
        }
    }
}

echo'<pre>',print_r($sums),'</pre>';
//Array
//(
//    [DOLLAR] => 30
//    [EURO] => 25
//)
```

**Do not** create a lot of variables with names like `$dol`, `$gbp` etc. Use one single array with keys.

Comment: My problem is the logic to get until I have the filtered array to add up. I imagine it like:
eur=0, gbp=0, usd=0, 
"foreach row where column no.2 has the value "XYZxxx": 
if col no. 10 = EUR then eur = eur+col no.9 value"; 
elseif col no. 10 = GBP gbp = gbp+col no9 value; 
else usd = usd + col no.9 value.

Comment: And where's the problem exactly?

Comment: That I don't know how can I specify these columns of the csv file, I mean how to tell php which one is which column of the current row.

Comment: I still don't understand. You know what `$array[index]` syntax means? Maybe you add some code to your question?

Comment: Yeah, of course. Ohh so you mean like looping through a multidimensional array with different index keys replacing the column header names?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: I would know how to do it with sql. But I didn't know how to navigate around in the content of the csv which I assume becomes a multidimensional array and has a lot of empty fields in between certain values.

Comment: What does `sql` do here? You have a csv file. You have a multidimensional array which you can navigate with `foreach`. Maybe it's time to show your code?

Comment: I advise you to print your multidminsional array and see what you have there. And what keys you can use to get values from it.